# Is it normal to have UDP packet loss with mtr to 8.8.8.8?

Tags: networking, ping

I have packet loss pinging using UDP with mtr  so it's normal to have packet loss outside when using UDP. Here is my traceroute result:

```
    My traceroute  [v0.93]
DEll-OptiPlex-780 (my wan ip)                                                                                                                                                                    2021-03-22T19:21:31+0200
Keys:  Help   Display mode   Restart statistics   Order of fields   quit
                                                                                                                                                                                      Packets               Pings
 Host                                                                                                                                                                               Loss%   Snt   Last   Avg  Best  Wrst StDev
 1. default gateway                                                                                                                                                                      0.0%   139   24.9  26.3  24.0 201.9  15.0
 2. 172.31.250.53                                                                                                                                                                    0.0%   139   25.9  28.2  24.8 209.4  15.9
 3. host-81.10.87.165.tedata.net                                                                                                                                                     0.0%   139   29.7  31.4  28.0 210.7  15.6
    host-81.10.87.161.tedata.net
 4. ip4.gtt.net                                                                                                                                                                      0.0%   139   33.0  34.6  29.0 243.9  19.0
    149.6.154.170
 5. te0-0-1-6.ccr21.mrs01.atlas.cogentco.com                                                                                                                                        10.9%   139   67.6  70.5  59.2 234.4  19.3
    et-0-0-8-0.cr6-mrs1.ip4.gtt.net
    te0-0-0-19.rcr21.mil01.atlas.cogentco.com
    ae10-392.cr5-lon2.ip4.gtt.net
    93.186.129.10
    80.81.68.121
    125.16.250.17
    te0-0-1-16.ccr21.mrs01.atlas.cogentco.com
 6. 72.14.196.122                                                                                                                                                                    5.0%   139   72.2  73.1  59.4 240.8  19.5
    72.14.197.198
    be2194.rcr21.mil01.atlas.cogentco.com
    be2189.rcr21.mil01.atlas.cogentco.com
    ip4.gtt.net
    ae22.cr10-lon1.ip4.gtt.net
    72.14.197.204
    ae21.cr10-lon1.ip4.gtt.net
 7. 72.14.209.236                                                                                                                                                                   39.9%   139   66.8  78.4  61.3 121.8   9.2
    209.85.172.66
    72.14.221.145
    72.14.216.154
    ix-ae-12-0.thar1.wi3-milan.as6453.net
    be2348.rcr21.b023101-0.lon13.atlas.cogentco.com
    72.14.204.72
    74.125.244.209
 8. 72.14.213.156                                                                                                                                                                   57.7%   138   66.7  76.6  59.7 233.2  25.1
    209.85.172.66
    ae39-xcr1.ltw.cw.net
    dns.google
 9. ae8-xcr1.lnt.cw.net                                                                                                                                                             86.9%   138   91.9  83.8  59.9  92.6  13.2
    74.125.245.225
    dns.google
10. google-gw.lnt.cw.net                                                                                                                                                            87.6%   138   91.7  82.0  59.4  94.5  14.0
    dns.google
    216.239.40.201
11. dns.google                                                                                                                                                                      94.2%   138   71.7  70.7  60.3  89.1   8.4
    74.125.242.97
```

when I ping with port 53

```
Keys:  Help   Display mode   Restart statistics   Order of fields   quit
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   Packets               Pings
 Host                                                                                                                                                                                                                            Loss%   Snt   Last   Avg  Best  Wrst StDev
 1. default gateway                                                                                                                                                                                                                  0.0%    38   24.4  24.9  24.2  25.7   0.3
 2. 172.31.250.53                                                                                                                                                                                                                 0.0%    38   27.1  26.2  24.9  31.2   1.1
 3. 81.10.87.161                                                                                                                                                                                                                  0.0%    38   30.1  29.4  27.9  31.7   0.7
    81.10.87.185
    81.10.87.165
 4. 149.6.154.170                                                                                                                                                                                                                 0.0%    38   30.3  30.6  28.8  36.9   2.1
    154.14.64.30
 5. 154.14.64.29                                                                                                                                                                                                                 18.4%    38   59.9  70.3  59.4 144.4  17.3
    125.16.250.17
    80.81.68.121
    149.14.124.33
    149.14.125.145
    149.14.248.121
    154.14.64.33
    149.14.124.73
 6. 46.33.86.206                                                                                                                                                                                                                  0.0%    38   90.2  71.4  59.6 101.4   9.2
    154.54.61.30
    193.251.255.70
    154.54.36.70
    72.14.222.118
    130.117.2.65
    80.77.2.153
    89.149.139.5
 7. 195.219.166.196                                                                                                                                                                                                               0.0%    38   61.7  72.9  59.9  89.9   9.4
    130.117.51.138
    108.170.252.241
    74.125.48.192
    209.85.172.66
    72.14.209.236
    74.125.244.209
    108.170.231.107
 8. 72.14.213.156                                                                                                                                                                                                                 0.0%    38   67.8  71.5  59.7  91.3  10.6
    209.85.248.229
    108.170.238.107
    142.250.46.97
    72.14.232.43
    216.239.51.9
    72.14.232.163
    195.2.26.25
 9. 72.14.238.234                                                                                                                                                                                                                32.4%    38   69.0  71.0  65.6  90.3   6.8
    172.253.72.111
    209.85.254.219
    172.253.68.213
    195.2.24.130
    72.14.239.144
    74.125.245.241
    142.251.50.137
10. 142.250.211.31                                                                                                                                                                                                               52.8%    37   68.5  74.0  67.0 128.3  15.5
    195.89.96.234
    142.250.212.245
    216.239.40.201
    108.170.232.181
    172.253.69.255
    216.239.49.181
    142.250.211.25
11. 108.170.246.129                                                                                                                                                                                                              97.2%    37   88.9  88.9  88.9  88.9   0.0
12. 172.253.69.59                                                                                                                                                                                                                94.6%    37   89.4  89.3  89.3  89.4   0.1
    172.253.65.209
13. (waiting for reply)
```

Comment: Your example doesn't show any errors. The information is insufficient. And to answer: Packet loss is never normal, pointing normally to network problems.

Comment: It looks like your ISP is using ECMP to load-balance between several upstream connections (and there's probably more ECMP going on upstream as well), and as a result of UDP probes having different ports every time, mtr is showing you a useless mix of 2-3 different paths... Consider using `mtr -P` with a fixed port number -- by changing it, you should be able to get 2-3 different "normal" traces. Add them to your question.

Comment: @harrymc Nitpick: Packet loss *that high* is not normal, but small amounts of packet loss (perhaps below 1%) are normal and a super important congestion signal until everything supports ECN. The myth that any packet loss is always bad is behind why we have a bufferbloat pandemic today.

Comment: @user1686 when pinging with static port i also  gets packets loss  the result are above